# Can't upload photo using paper clip in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, rubygems

I use this code to upload photos, I find that it is not successfully upload photo, but other content can be updated.

```
<% semantic_remote_form_for(@product, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>  
  <% f.inputs do %>  
    <%= f.input :title, :label => "Name" %>  
    <%= f.input :category , :include_blank => false , :label => "Category" %>  
    <%= f.input :price, :label => "Price" %>  
    <%= f.input :photo, :label => "Photo" %>
  <% end %>  
  <%= f.buttons %>  
<% end %>
```

The code from server log:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Disabling
>   sessions for a single controller has
>   been deprecated. Sessions are now lazy
>   loaded. So if you don't access them,
>   consider them off. You can still
>   modify the session cookie options with
>   request.session_options.. (called from
>   /onlineStore/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6)
>
> Processing ProductsController#update
>   (for ::1 at 2010-01-23 22:03:54) [PUT]
>   Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save Product",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"vOvxOPYYE1wRGDYTEH5ciHrNJXUpGTJku3etIpCmf1c=",
>   "id"=>"33",
>   "product"=>{"price"=>"874",
>   "title"=>"Other products",
>   "category_id"=>"142"}, "_"=>""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised it worked at all, since Javascript is not supposed to be able to upload files via AJAX. Was the new switch the fact that you made it a *remote* form for the product? Since even though it's a gem helping with the semantic form building, even it shouldn't be able to do file uploads in that fashion.

Comment: Sorry, I type wrong.... ... so, I can't use the remote form?? But I want the stuff reload all using js. How can I do?